# Incapaz de llamar funcion js desde jsp usando Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring

He intentado diversas formas para ejecutar un javascript desde un jsp en un proyecto que usa Spring MVC, todas han fallado:

1. [Spring MVC – How to include JS or CSS files in a JSP page](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/)

Esta es la estructura del proyecto:

[image: Project structure]

El index.jsp (en concreto deseo llamar la función hello() que esta ubicado en un archivo js externo):

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="<c:url value="/WEB-INF/resources/scripts.js" />"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="hello()">Click here...</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Aquí esta el dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.javatechig.controller" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

El web.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>test</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Por último scripts.js:

```
function hello(){
    alert('Hola');
}
```

Cuando presiono el botón aparecen los siguientes errores:

- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
  (Not Found)
- ReferenceError: Can't find variable: hello

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta la obtuve de Stack Overflow en inglés, el problema era que declaraba la ruta para una carpeta de recursos:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" />
```

Sin embargo nunca la usaba. Había que cambiar ésta línea:

```
<script src="<c:url value="/WEB-INF/resources/scripts.js" />"></script>
```

Por ésta otra y listo:

```
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/scripts.js" />"></script>
```

Este es el enlace de la [respuesta original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46870067/unable-to-call-javascript-in-jsp-using-spring-mvc/46873188#46873188) en inglés.